# Console.OutputEncoding breaks batch files

Tags: .net, batch-file, encoding, console-application, windows-server-2008

On a Windows 2008 (non-R2) server, I experience the same behaviour as [described in this MSDN forum posting](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/e448b241-e250-4dcb-8ecd-361e00920dde/consoleoutputencoding-breaks-batch-files?forum=netfxbcl):

> Whenever I run a .NET Console application that changes the [`Console.OutputEncoding`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console.outputencoding) to UTF-8, no more batch files can be executed until I close and reopen the CMD window.

This only happens on Windows 2008 (non-R2), this does not happen on Windows 2008 R2 or Windows 2012 servers.

I initially discovered this when my [CS-Script](http://www.csscript.net/) files "broke" my backup batch files.

As soon as the .NET Console application exits, running further batch files simply immediately return, no matter whether they simple `echo` a text or `start` some programs.

This is the minimum program to generate the erroneous behaviour:

```
namespace utf8
{
    using System;
    using System.Text;

    internal static class Program
    {
        private static void Main()
        {
            Console.OutputEncoding = Encoding.UTF8;
        }
    }
}
```

I'm completely clueless what's going on here and how to fix it.

**My question:**

- Any idea why setting the `Console.OutputEncoding` breaks further batch processing?
- Any hints on how to solve this (if I have/don't have access to the .NET Console sources)?

**Update 1:**

For my own code, this seems to fix it:

```
namespace utf8
{
    using System;
    using System.Text;

    internal static class Program
    {
        private static void Main()
        {
            var before = Console.OutputEncoding;
            Console.OutputEncoding = Encoding.UTF8;
            try
            {

                // ... Do some processing...

            }
            finally
            {
                Console.OutputEncoding = before;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I.e. after running the above code, the current CMD window still *is* able to run batch files.

**Update 2:**

If anyone ever comes here with CS-Script behaving like stated above; [version 3.9.8.0 of CS-Script](https://csscriptsource.codeplex.com/releases/view/614649) fixes this. So simply update to 3.9.8.0 or newer.

Comment: Wouldn't you be better asking Mircosoft?

Comment: @AshBurlaczenko Your comment seems to fit well under virtually _any_ question here on Stack Overflow, doesn't it?

Comment: Well you said it only effects server 2012 so it appears to be a problem for MS OS team.

Comment: Does it happen if you run your batch with `cmd /u` option?

Comment: @Trigger Just tested it. If my tests were correct, the answer is: **Yes**, it also happens with `cmd /u`. I.e. no more batch files run after my test Console app changes the encoding.

Comment: Hmm, I suppose you want to type `chcp 437` next.